# Can't call MainActivity methods from its class

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I looked everywhere and couldn't find what's wrong with my code, I am simply trying to call a MainActivity method from its own class:

**MainActivity.java:**

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TestiClass testi = new TestiClass(this,this);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void testi_method(){

    }

}
```

**TestiClass.java:**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;

public class TestiClass {

    private Activity mActivity;
    private Context mContext;

    TestiClass(Activity activity ,Context context){
        this.mActivity = activity;
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    void test(){
        mActivity.testi_method(); //????
    }

}
```

`mActivity.testi_method()` says - cannot resolve method... 
Any Thoughts?

Comment: your test class is using android.app.Activity not your MainActivity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this must be your implementation then it is an easy fix:

```
private final MainActivity mainActivity;
private final Context context;

TestiClass(MainActivity mainActivity, Context context){
    this.mainActivity = mainActivity;
    this.context = context;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont Use Activity, Use The Class you want to call the method. here is fix:

```
   import android.app.Activity;
   import android.content.Context;

   public class TestiClass {

   private MainActivity  mActivity;
   private Context mContext;

   TestiClass(MainActivity activity ,Context context){
    this.mActivity = activity;
    this.mContext = context;
     }

     void test(){
      mActivity.testi_method(); 
      }
    }
```